# How can I create multiple subs using a for-loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I'd like to create multiple subs with a similiar name. Here is my Excel VBA code:

```
' sub main
Sub LoopSubsTest()


' defining an array
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("solver_inv_1", "solver_inv_2")

' for-loop
For i = 1 to 2

' sub sub
Sub myarray.Item(g)()

' this is the code part
...

End Sub
Next i

End Sub
```

Of course, Any other solutions are welcomed. Unfortunately, this code violates VBA coding that Subs cannot be embed in another Subs. How can I create multiple subs using a for-loop in Excel VBA? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of extra code that could eliminated by adding 1 or 2 parameters to an existing sub. What method are you using to actally write the module code?

Comment: It's mainly the Excel Solver's code. I'd like to create many Subs related to Excel Solver. So this is the reason why I try generate these Subs with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Application.Run**

Here you find two approaches to execute named Subs:

**[1] Constant plus Counter**

```
Sub LoopSubsConst()
Const MYSUB = "solver_inv_"
' for-loop
For i = 1 To 2
    Run MYSUB & i
Next i
End Sub
```

**[2] Named array items**

```
Sub LoopSubsArray()
' declare array
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("solver_inv_1", "solver_inv_2")
' run subs
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    Run myarray(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

**Note**
`Application.Run` can receive up to 30 arguments corresponding to the order in the called subs, too (caveat: only values, no objects as argument).

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can execute the Subs. However, is there any approaches to generate them AND execute them as well?

Comment: You can integrate this code e.g. in a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` routine in `ThisWorkbook` code module (first module in MS Excel Objects) automatically opening when you open this workbook.